# How to take the return value from method in a method

Tags: javascript, jsf

Here I am returning my count variable from a function in Javascript as shown:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
            var count = 0;
            function resetGroupsSelector(groupId){
            //alert(groupId);
            console.log("search_report_form:"+groupId)
            //alert("search_report_form:"+groupId)
            var id = "search_report_form:"+groupId;

            //alert(count);
            if(document.getElementById(id).checked) 
                {
                count=count+1;
                alert(count);
                }
            else
                {
                count=count-1;
                alert(count);
                }

            return count;
            }
</script>
```

Now, how do I get my count value from my JSF code in order to print it with htm() function?

```
final class GroupsSelector extends BaseRenderablePanel<GroupsSelector> {
        private GroupsSelector group(LabourInputReportCriteria.Level level) {
            HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox box = new HtmlSelectBooleanCheckbox();
            boolean isSelected = selections.isGroupSelected(level);
            box.setSelected(isSelected);
            // box.setDisabled(isDaySelectedOnFirst(level));
            String id="groupBy" + level.getClass().getSimpleName();
            box.setId(id);

            box.setOnclick("resetGroupsSelector('"+id+"')");
            box.addValueChangeListener(u.addExpressionValueChangeListener("#{reportSearchCriteriaModel.groupBy}"));
            HtmlOutputText labelComponent = new HtmlOutputText();

            labelComponent.setValue(getGroupSelectionValue(level));
            tr().td();
            html(box);

            //html("&nbsp;");

            html(labelComponent);
            //html("<script> function resetGroupsSelector() {  var x = document.getElementById('search_report_form:groupByWeekLevel'); alert(x); } </script>");

            endTd().endTr();
            return this;
        }
```

Please help me.

Thanks,
Shruthi S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. However, if you want to get the a hit counter i.e. how many times has a jsf page been visited. Your best option is to use a @Singleton session bean, jsf @ManageBean and @SessionScoped beans as follows:

```
@Singleton
```

`public class IndexCounterBean {`

```
private int hits = 1;

// Increment and return the number of hits
public int getHits() {
    return hits++;
}
```

`}`

Then create a jsf @SessionScoped @ManagedBean to give you access to your counter as follows:

`@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class IndexCount implements Serializable{`

```
    @EJB
    private IndexCounterBean counterBean;

    private int hitCount;

    public IndexCount() {
        this.hitCount = 0;
    }

    public int getHitCount() {
        hitCount = counterBean.getHits();
        return hitCount;
    }

    public void setHitCount(int newHits) {
        this.hitCount = newHits;
    }
}
```

then, from a jsf (.xhtml) page, print your counter as follows:

```
<h:outputText value="#{indexCount.hitCount} Visits"/>
```

The counter will be incremented everytime the page is requested.